# Cannot send headers; headers already sent in

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax

I have tried all solution available in stackoverflow and stackexchange but not able to resolve it.

I have override Head.php in my module and i am using AjaxCart.

Whenever i enable my module i am getting error header already sent.

Here is exact error what i am getting.

```
Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /public_html/app/code/local/[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/Html/Head.php, line 1
```

Here is the code of `Head.php`

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Block_Html_Head extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
{
    protected function &_prepareStaticAndSkinElements($format, array $staticItems, array $skinItems, $mergeCallback = null)
    {
        //Logic
    }
}
```

Here is the code of `IndexController.php` of `AjaxCart`

```
public function indexAction(){
    //Logic
    //Response
    $this->getResponse()->clearHeaders()->setHeader('Content-type','application/json',true);
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($json_encode));
}
```

Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: have done some echo, print_r, var_dump at controller

Comment: Also check,have any space issue before start <?php at `Head.php`

Comment: @AmitBera i have checked their is no space before `<?php` and check their is no `echo` or `print_r` in controller.

Comment: kya be .. aayse ..kyase hoga.. Complier enable ha ya nahi check kar

Comment: @AmitBera lol desi language

Comment: it's clearly a space issue on first line as mention @AmitBera

Comment: is  the issue still alive ?

Comment: @AmitBera yes sir issue still alive :)